# Как отправить post запрос в request с API ключом

Tags: python, requests

Делаю телеграм бота для продаж, и когда дело дошло до внутреннего баланса возникла проблема.

В документации сайта (через которого проходят все финансовые дела в боте) сказано:`Для получения информации о балансе через API необходимо отправить запрос на выделенный URL-адрес, передав нужные параметры через POST` . Я понимаю что это можно сделать через библиотеку `request`, но как?

URL на который нужно отправить запрос - `https://payok.io/api/balance`

Та документация - https://payok.io/cabinet/documentation/doc_api_balance

Comment: `https://payok.io/api/balance?api_id="API_ID"&api_key="API_KEY"`, внутри кавычек вставляешь данные (_при запросе, ссылка без кавычек_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметры запроса удобно передавать в `params=` как словарь

Пример:

```
import requests


url = "https://payok.io/api/balance"
params = {
    "API_ID": API_ID,
    "API_KEY": API_KEY,
}
rs = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(rs)

rs.raise_for_status()  # Выбрасывает исключение при плохом ответе

print(rs.json())
```

Comment: Всё хорошо response код 200, но когда я попробовал получить текст т.е print(rs.text.) я получил {"status":"error","error_code":"1","error_text":"Не указан идентификатор API; Параметр API_ID"} что делать?

Comment: @Grum, убедитесь, что правильно заполнили API_ID и API_KEY, мб ошиблись. Еще можно посмотреть какой запрос был отправлен включив логирование: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d9baad77b9365e6347afc83cd999d519d424ec57/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L7-L28